# composer.phar always installs in /bin/php-5.5.8/

Tags: php, json, composer-php

I am running on a Windows machine. I installed WT-NMP and I am trying to install composer.phar. No matter from what folder I run this

```
php -r "eval('?>'.file_get_contents('https://getcomposer.org/installer'));"
```

it always installs in the /bin/php-5.5.8/ instead of the /www/project folder where I want it. Because of this, whenever I try to run

```
composer update
```

I receive an error that it can't find the composer.json file (because the json file is in www/project but it is searching for it in /bin/php-5.5.8 instead). I tried everything that I could think of but I can't get it to work.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could try to find out the reason why it does what you don't like, but the installer script essentially only checks some settings of the PHP used before downloading the .phar file because debugging things inside the .phar is problematic, i.e. it would be a support nightmare if you'd simply download the pure .phar and try to run it if your PHP is unable to do so.

Long story short: You can simply copy or move the downloaded composer.phar to any location you like, and it will work.

Comment: I tried doing that already. When I move the composer.phar file manually into /www/project/ and try to run 'composer update' from that location, I receive the following error: 'Composer could not find a composer.json file in /bin/php-5.5.8'. My composer.json file is in /www/project/ where I have my site and the composer.phar file after manually moving it there.

Comment: Then something is weird with your installation of PHP. It seems like PHP is always targeted at that directory. Could you investigate if there is any "php.bat" file with some weird setting.

Comment: This is the contents of php.bat inside /bin/: `@PUSHD "c:\wt\bin\php-5.5.8"
@"c:\wt\bin\php-5.5.8\php.exe" -c "c:\wt\conf" %*
@POPD
` I think you're right. This might be the problem. What should I change it to?

Comment: I believe these lines with `PUSHD` and `POPD` should be commented out or removed. I don't know if this has any side effects on your installation of PHP, so be sure to reverse it if things go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

you only need to specify where you want to install composer by changing PHP`s current working directory with chdir:

```
C:\WT-NMP\bin\php.bat -r "chdir('C:/WT-NMP/WWW'); eval('?>'.file_get_contents('https://getcomposer.org/installer'));"
```

an odd solution to an odd installation method ;)